# bcadd function not adding correctly

Tags: php, floating-point, sum, precision, bcmath

I have a problem in my php code where it didn't sum two floating point numbers. For this below code snippet it shows the output of "0.00108225".

```
print_r(bcadd(0.00108225, 0.00008892,8));
```

It shows correct output if I add it in a normal way. So is there any another way to get correct solution in bcmath module rather than using normal way?

Comment: the bcmath library works with strings, not with floats.... use `print_r(bcadd('0.00108225', '0.00008892', 8));`

Comment: Thank You.. :) It works perfectly now.